USB tty disappeared after performing a 4/5G modem command
I have a system which consists of a raspberry pi 5 board and a SIM8200 LTE/5GNR modem which is connected to it via USB. I used to communicate with the modem through the minicom terminal. The problem is that after I issued the next AT command (I followed the steps from this tutorial: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM820X_RNDIS_Dail-up): at+cusbcfg=usbid,1e0e,9011 - in order to be able to access 5G NR on my raspberry pi - I couldn't connect to any USB device after the first reboot of the raspberry pi, and, moreover, I noticed that there is no /dev/ttyUSB* device present at all. I tried to issue a couple of suggested commands in order to get back the USB descriptors, but I had no success at all. I tried even to reboot both the modem and the raspberry pi, but again, no success.

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post ... edit the post ... do not write question in a comment

According to the wiki that you linked, this is an expected behaviour and you can restore the ttyUSB with:

Ubuntu system
sudo su
sudo echo 1e0e 9011 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id


Raspbian and CentOS systems
sudo su
sudo modprobe option
sudo sh -c 'echo "1e0e 9011" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id'
sudo sh -c 'echo "1e0e 9018" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id'
sudo sh -c 'echo "1e0e 901E" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id'



